# block push of trivial merge to git server

Tags: git, bash, git-branch, githooks, git-merge

A while back I [asked our developers to use rebase instead of merge before pushing](http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.comp.finance.mifos.devel/9491/focus=9597). Eliminating trivial merges makes for a much easier to follow commit graph (ie: gitk, git log).

Sometimes folks still accidentally do trivial merges, then push. Does anyone have handy or have tips for writing a server-side hook that blocks trivial merges?

By "trivial merge", I mean a merge without conflicts. [Here's an example](http://mifos.git.sourceforge.net/git/gitweb.cgi?p=mifos/head;a=commit;h=c516520a9c37944c96162ffd85c00f68b81786a6), and [here's a better explanation of a trivial merge in git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1824264/what-is-a-trivial-merge-in-git/1824297#1824297).

**Update Wed Nov 10 01:26:41 UTC 2010**: great comments, all! Thank you.

- Consider the following: all I'm really asking folks to do is this:

  - if `git pull --ff-only` fails, do `git pull --rebase` instead of `git pull`
- git.git only has one or two committers, right? In theory, it should be easy to follow the commit graph, but it looks pretty messy to me.

**Update Thu Nov 11 23:49:35 UTC 2010**:

- [here's a gist with some in-progress work](https://gist.github.com/673438)
- another idea is to prevent trivial merges on the client end, with a "git push" [wrapper](http://article.gmane.org/gmane.comp.version-control.git/92920)

**Update Wed Dec 15 18:34:52 UTC 2010**:

- [adymitruk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/217284/adymitruk) is close! Just one case is still unresolved: non-trivial merges must still work.
- A rather complete [test suite](https://gist.github.com/737842) is available, check it out.
- I asked for help on a (the?) [git mailing list](http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.comp.version-control.git/163788).

Comment: How do you define "trivial merge?"  How do you expect to be able to differentiate between trivial merges and non-trivial merges?

Comment: I added that, starting with *By "trivial merge"...*

Comment: There are lots of arguments against rebasing instead of merging. Personally I'd hate to be forced to rebase. Just sayin ;)

Comment: well, you cannot know the difference between a trivial 'pull'-merge and a merge without conflicts of a topic/feature branch.

Comment: Ah, missed that, Adam.  Note that which files were conflicted is not stored in the commit in any reliable way (it is in the template commit message, but that can be edited).  The only way you could test this would be to replay the merge and see if any conflicts arise.  However, I would argue that eliminating trivial merges actually loses history and makes the history graph less accurate.

Comment: As August says, you should really think twice about doing this. Your standard for whether a merge is necessary (presence of conflicts) makes little sense. You can resolve merge conflicts in a merge or a rebase, and you can combine content without conflicts using a merge or a rebase. What matters is the history of the commits. If what you want to do is "incorporate the work done on this feature branch" then the way to represent that is a merge. Merges do not have to make history hard to follow - look at git.git.

Comment: Thanks for the comments, folks! I just updated the original question, attempting to address these comments.

Comment: I added a proper answer below.. Didn't bother addressing the octopus merge though.

Comment: anyone else want to test the script below? I fixed the last word count issue just now.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I came across this piece of code, while trying to find a solution. It doesn't do exactly what you want, but it should be ez to add extra branch names on the if statement.

Works for me, so far. it forces pull --rebase for the same branch and lets regular merges with other branches go through.

All credits go to the original author.

```
#!/bin/bash
#
# This git update hook will refuse unnecessary merge commits caused by pulling
# from being pushed to a shared repository. These commits make following the
# history of a project difficult and are always avoidable with rebasing.
#
# by Scott Kyle (appden)
# modified by Olivier Refalo (orefalo)

refname="$1"
oldrev="$2"
newrev="$3"

# if this is not run as a hook, you may have messed up
if [ -z "$GIT_DIR" -o -z "$refname" -o -z "$oldrev" -o -z "$newrev" ]; then
    echo "Usage: GIT_DIR=<path> $0 <ref> <oldrev> <newrev>" >&2
    exit 1
fi

# if the new revision is all 0's then it's a commit to delete a ref
zero="0000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
# also check if the new revision is not a commit or is not a fast forward
# detect branch deletion, branch creation... and more
if [ "${refname#refs/heads/}" = "master" ] || [ "$newrev" = "$zero" ] || [ "$oldrev" = "$zero" ] || [ $(git cat-file -t $newrev) != "co
mmit" ] || [ $(git merge-base $oldrev $newrev) != "$oldrev" ]; then
    exit 0
fi

# loop through merges in the push only following first parents
for merge in $(git rev-list --first-parent --merges $oldrev..$newrev --); do
    # lazily create the revision list of this branch prior to the push
    [ -z "$revlist" ] && revlist=$(git rev-list $oldrev)
    # check if the second parent of the merge is already in this branch
    if grep -q $(git rev-parse $merge^2) <<< "$revlist"; then
        cat >&2 <<-EOF
            *** PUSH REJECTED ***
            *** TRIVIAL merge detected on local branch ${refname#refs/heads/}
            *** To fix: git rebase origin/${refname#refs/heads/}
            ***
            *** Next time use: git pull --rebase
            ***
            *** Permanent fix: git config [--global] branch.autosetuprebase always
            *** Then for existing branches: git config branch.<name>.rebase true
        EOF
        exit 1
    fi
done

echo -Info- Clean history successfully preserved!
exit 0
```

Comment: This blocks nontrivial merges too. See https://gist.github.com/737842 . I added this code to that gist, just type "make" to run tests.

Comment: When deployed on the server(update hook) it forces users into 'pull --rebase'. A regular merge from another branch works fine, but from the same branch will fail on a trivial merge

Comment: Ah, I see. Sorry, should have read your description more thoroughly. When I posted this question a year ago, I think I was looking for something that *would* allow a nontrivial merge from origin/master to master, so folks could still do merges. I ran into several integrations in my old job (working on Mifos) where rebasing was difficult but merging was easy. Now that I'm more comfortable with rebase, I'd probably use the update script you presented. Let's close the book on this one. You win!

Answer (score 4):

This **update hook** will check if you are pushing to specific branches (it allows trivial merges in wip, topic and other branches).

This does not bother with the rest of the parents on octopus merges as it only references the 2nd parent in each merge commit being pushed. Please feel free to update the script.

UPDATE: Reserved branches are required to exist on the remote.

```
#!/bin/bash
refname="$1"
oldrev="$2"
newrev="$3"
branches="refs/heads/hotfixes refs/heads/dev refs/heads/qa refs/heads/master"
cont="no"
for branch in $branches ; do
  if [[ $refname == $branch ]] ; then
    cont="yes"
  fi
done
if [[ $cont == "no" ]] ; then
  exit 0
fi
echo "inspecting branch $refname for trivial merges" >&2
hashes="$(git log --format=%H --merges $oldrev..$newrev)"
for hash in $hashes ; do
  echo "checking merge commit $hash" >&2
  cont="no"
  for branch in $branches ; do
    if [[ $refname == $branch ]] ; then
      continue
    fi
    # if [[ "$(git log --format=%H $hash^2 ^$branch | wc -l)" == "0" ]] ; then
    if [[ "$(git log --format=%H $hash^2 ^$branch | wc -l)" == "    0" ]] ; then
      cont="yes"
    fi
  done
  if [[ $cont == "no" ]] ; then
    echo "No trivial merges allowed. Please rebase and push again." >&2
    exit 1
  fi
done
exit 0
```

Comment: @adymitruk - You should use `&&` instead of `AND`. It would also benefit from some line breaks inside the `[[` and `]]`.

Comment: Agreed.. this was more pseudo code. Please suggest a replacement for the if condition and I'll edit the response.

Comment: Doesn't work for me as a pre-receive hook, even after replacing `AND` with `&&`, removing some linebreaks, and using bash's `=~` operator for regex matches. I made a local repo, cloned it and did a trivial merge on the "qa" branch, but I was still able to push the trivial merge back to origin. Here's what I've got so far: http://pastey.net/142760 / https://gist.github.com/673438

Comment: Sorry. This is meant as an update hook. If you are using gitolite, make sure you use update.secondary and use the installer to push the change through. I'll update the answer to specify which hook.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are doing with the while loop there. The git update hook receives 3 arguments: the branch name, the commit sha of where it is, the commit sha of where it will be. This hook is called once for each branch that is going to be updated when something is pushed to the repo.

Comment: I don't know what I was doing with the pre-receive stuff. I *think* I got it working--by mere luck--as an update script. Here's what I've got: http://pastey.net/142866 . Can you explain what the two "git log" commands do?

Comment: Oi, more issues. For the version I "got working" (or so I thought), it also blocks non-trivial merges, ie: merges in which conflicts have been resolved. Heh, I think I've finally reached my limit in how deep I want to get in git. :) Thanks again, I'm sure this is a great start for someone with more git experience/time to hack than me! I'll wait to mark the "accepted answer" for a completed update hook.

Comment: the git log commands do this: --format=%H means just show the complete 40 char SHA-1 of the commit, ^$hash^2 means exclude commits from the 2nd parent of the commit represented by $hash (the ^ at the front means exclude these commits from the result, the ^2 means 2nd parent of the commit), qa means include the commits from qa. The combination is a set operation, make sense?

Comment: I can get this working for you. Can you paste in what you have currently and tell me where it's not working?

Comment: That's not going to work... at the very top you have "$refname == $branch". $refname will be something like refs/heads/master, right? so that will never equal $branch. Will you create a test case? Something that proves this actually does what it should?

Comment: Nope, but I can see that the script is still broken, at least on my system (Ubuntu 10.04 desktop). The output of wc will never equal `"0"`. I get `      0       0       0` from `cat /dev/null | wc`. A test case would really help you prove that this actually works.

Comment: I was missing the -l. Perhaps you could add the test case instead of dumping ALL the work on someone that's really trying hard to help you??? :) .. anyway, I updated again.

Comment: Fair enough, I'll get to it eventually. But generally the best person to write a test case is the original developer. :) I did spend a number of hours on this already, but I'm sure you have too!

Comment: Well, if you want to satisfy a criteria, YOU provide the test ;) Anywho.. I think I pinned the issues to the wc call. Let me know.

Comment: Nice work, Adam! Here's a unit test suite: https://gist.github.com/737842 . It shows that trivial merges work on branches other than those in $branches, trivial merges may not be pushed to master, and that rebased commits may be pushed to master.

Comment: Whoops! I guess non-trivial merges are actually **not** allowed, even though they need to be. I fixed the the nontrivial_merge test case in https://gist.github.com/737842 .