# How to get rid of "merge branch..." automatic messages in git repository

Tags: git, version-control, dvcs

Our team recently started using Git.

The main workflow we're doing is simple, (as we're not yet ninja-trained on more complex commands and workflows with it):

1. Developer A commits new code (few commits).
2. Developer A pushes changes to main repository.
3. Developer B commits, tries to push (gets a message saying he must PULL).
4. Developer B pulls, then pushes.

After some time, the repository log looks like this:

[image]

I would like to avoid this, since it makes the log pretty much unreadable, not to mention in some cases the 'merging' that is going on does not change any files (i can't see any change made by it).

Are we doing something wrong in the way we work with Git? should we do it differently?

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4138285/block-push-of-trivial-merge-to-git-server

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're not doing anything wrong, that's just Git recording that a change was made to the repository by merging two sets of changes.

If you use `git rebase` before pushing, or `git pull --rebase` when pulling, then the merge commits will not be kept in the history.  See http://arjanvandergaag.nl/blog/clarify-git-history-with-merge-commits.html for more.

Comment: TortoiseGit does not offer the "pull --rebase" option in its UI. Is there any other UI tool that is better then?

Comment: I don't know, sorry, I only use the command-line tools. There must be some way to rebase in TortoiseGit, if you can't do it when pulling then you should be able to do an explicit rebase step. If TortoiseGit doesn't have a Rebase command you could set the branch to _always_ rebase when pulling by running `git config branch.<your_branch_name>.rebase true`

Comment: The rebase flow doesn't really lend itself to GUI

Comment: @lysergic-acid for example, an interactive rebase can do a lot of different things, such as replay history with pauses for editing, executing arbitrary shell commands in the middle, reorder history, squash multiple commits into a single commit, etc.  GUI tools tend to hide that level of complexity in my experience.
In general, many users are scared of rebase *because* it can alter history, and the GUI might want to hide it for that reason, as well.

Comment: @JonathanWakely are there any caveats to using this configuration option?

Comment: @lysergic-acid, it means all pull operations will rebase so you should understand what that means before using it. There has been lots written about the pros and cons of rebasing. One downside is you can't rebase if you have uncommitted changes in your working tree.