# Git pre receive hook - allow push but block merge commits

Tags: git, gitlab, githooks

I have situation where I want to allow developers to directly push changes to master, blocking at the same time their local branch merges. For example if they perform merge from the origin into the local master and try to push I would like to identify this as a merge commit and block it. Gitlab branch protector does not assist in that way,  also according to their support the only option is a pre-receive hook. How can I setup such pre-receive hook?

Comment: The [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8936474/213871) to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4138285/block-push-of-trivial-merge-to-git-server) seems to have exactly what you are asking for.